# How to feed lark with an antlr g4 C# grammar?

Tags: c#, python, antlr, lark-parser

I would like to use lark to generate a parser for C# 6.

I found a [C# 6 antlr grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/csharp/CSharpParser.g4) but it does not work out-of-the-box with lark.

Is there anybody who could tell me how to reformat the g4 grammar to something I can feed lark with?

It seems that the format between what expect lark and g4 are kinda different.

```
from lark import Lark

filename = 'grammar.bnf'

with open(filename,'r') as file:
    output = file.read()

parser = Lark(output, start='compilation_unit')
```

`grammar.bnf` contains the C# 6 grammar I mentioned [above](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/csharp/CSharpParser.g4), with the starting point being `compilation_unit`.

Excerpt from the original bnf file:

```
parser grammar CSharpParser;

options { tokenVocab=CSharpLexer; }

// entry point
compilation_unit
    : BYTE_ORDER_MARK? extern_alias_directives? using_directives?
      global_attribute_section* namespace_member_declarations? EOF
    ;

//B.2 Syntactic grammar

//B.2.1 Basic concepts

namespace_or_type_name 
    : (identifier type_argument_list? | qualified_alias_member) ('.' identifier type_argument_list?)*
    ;

[Rest of the file]
```

Note that I removed everything before the entry point `compilation_unit`:

```
parser grammar CSharpParser;

options { tokenVocab=CSharpLexer; }
```

Comment: Why do you think you can process ANTLR grammars with Lark? Lark handles BNF, not ANTLR’s flavored BNF-like syntax. Besides that, I see that Lark handles LR grammars, while ANTLR does LL grammars. In short: you can’t do this with Lark.

Comment: @BartKiers that was my point thought there was a way to convert the antlr bnf to lark ebnf variant, they look similar.
Thanks for your answer, guess I need to stick to antlr then =/

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to easily/automatically convert ANTLR's LL grammar to a generic (Lark) (E)BNF LR variant. Yes, I'd stick with ANTLR.

Comment: You can actually use Lark to parse anything that ANTLR can parse. You just have to convert the syntax.